# Bond Angle in a water molecule

Tags: water, molecules

I recently started up reaching up on the Feynman lectures on Physics and in Vol I,Chap 1-2,Feynman states that the bond angle between the hydrogen and oxygen atom is 105° 3′.

I know that the bond angle is 104.48° and can be rounded up to 105° ,but what does the 3′ that comes after the 105° mean?

Comment: Does he give a citation for the source of that value? Can it be that the angle measurements have improved and/or the definition has changed slightly?

Comment: Nope,not that I can find of in the book.

Comment: I know that there are some false claims about "water processing machines" going around that make claims that the bond angle of water is supposed to have changed over the course of the past century, which is supposed to cause cancer, which, of course, the miracle machine can magically correct. I am pretty sure those claims are based on a slight shift of measured and/or predicted values for the bond angle over the years. Since Feynman's book has been around for a while it may be quoting one of those older values. It may be a fun exercise to go into the library and to get a bunch of old values.

Comment: The *3'* is three [minutes of arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_of_arc) i.e. $3/60$ or 0.05 of a degree. Why Feynmann's value differs from modern estimates I don't know.